# How do I host my Discord bot on the same server on which my website runs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, hosting

So I own a website which runs on a server and I want to host my Discord bot which has been written in JS on the same server as my website, Is this even possible? IF yes then how cause after searching on the internet I only found free hosting tutorials but nothing of this sort. I use CPanel for the server management.

Comment: This isnt `javascript` or `discord.js` related. Add the `node.js` tag.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot host your discord bot on a client-side website.
What you can do is transfer your client-side website to an express.js website (which is server-side), and add your bot into the express.js website code.

And host it in [Heroku](https://heroku.com).

Answer (score 0):

You may not host your discord bot ( server - side application ) on a client - side panel, however from your question I assume you are attempting to do so because you need to communicate between the discord bot and the website, for the same I would like to suggest [Asynchronus JavaScript and XML](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) AJAX for short.